# Maintain aspect ration of first item in two item Material UI grid while second item determines height of grid

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a row-direction Material UI grid where the left item is a 1:1 aspect ratio image and the right item is some details, buttons, etc. The grid height should be based on the height of the right item height because the text and buttons can make the grid taller. I would like the left item to maintain the same aspect ratio when the grid gets taller.

[image: Here is a mockup of what I mean]

I seem to be able to get the resizing part working, but the aspect ratio of the image seems to be all over the place - even images of the same size will be rendered in different ways.

Comment: It's a difficult task for the browser (probably impossible) because if your element will define the height then its width need to first be known and if its width is known then you know the remaining width for the square element so you also know its height and it will not necessarely be the same as the height of the content.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate it on my side? Cause I seem to be able to get the behavior I want by manually changing the width of the image, but can't find a way to automatically set it.

Comment: If you can think of an algorithm to go by, then yes. Otherwise it is probably not possible.

Comment: Have you tried making sure that your image doesn't have width fixed and just put height: 100% (and width: auto) . This should keep your aspect ratio if the min-width, max-width, min-height and max-height doesn't overwrite it. Or I am missing something?

Comment: We ended up just going with something else, but I think I did try that. I think it wasn't working for the reasons explained above